# Selection from sql db with identical names

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как исключить из запроса значения результатов по значению test, data которые не находятся в диапазоне, например (4, 9) в таблице данных

```
 id       name   data  
 1        test1    3
 1        res      sdf
 1        tost     asd
 1        test2    6
 2        test8    12
```

Необходимо, чтобы id 1 был исключен из запроса, так как 6 попадает в диапазон. результат будет только id 2

Comment: Это stackoverflow на русском и вопросы задаются тоже на русском. Похоже речь идёт об операторе between.

Comment: Спасибо поправил вопрос

Comment: несколько странно искать диапазоны в строковых значениях

Comment: Что поделаешь если  таблица такая

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, странно, что диапазон нужно искать в строках... Как вариант, можно взять все ид, которые не подходят, и исключить их:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE CASE WHEN (data < 4 OR data > 9) THEN 0 ELSE -1 END = -1 AND name LIKE '%test%')
```

Дописал про "test", если правильно понял. То есть в `name` есть совпадение с строкой `test` и диапазон `data` [4,9], такие ид исключить.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a0d80/3

Comment: Да спасибо примерно то что нужно. От усталости уже каша походу в голове

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE name LIKE 'test%' AND id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE 'test%' AND (data BETWEEN 4 AND 9)
```